# Cannot understand the debug procedure in scala in intellij idea

Tags: scala

Today I tried to debug the scala program in intellij idea, I met one phenomenon which I cannot understand.
The program is as follows:

```
import java.io._
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

class Person(val name: String) extends Serializable {
  val friends = new ArrayBuffer[Person]
  // OK—ArrayBuffer is serializable
  def description = name + " with friends " +
    friends.map(_.name).mkString(", ")
}

object TestSec08 extends App{
  val fred = new Person("Fred")
  val wilma = new Person("Wilma")
  val barney = new Person("Barney")
  fred.friends += wilma
  fred.friends += barney
  wilma.friends += barney
  barney.friends += fred

  val out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.obj"))
  out.writeObject(fred)
  out.close()
  val in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("test.obj"))
  val savedFred = in.readObject().asInstanceOf[Person]
  in.close()

  savedFred.description
  savedFred.friends.map(_.description)
}
```

Then I debug it from the first line, when it goes to the 4th line, which is "fred.friends += wilma", in my sense, it should continue to the next line-"fred.friends += barney". But instead of that, it goes back to the first line which confused me very much. Can anybody explain the reason why it happens like this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`val` declaration in a class body is implemented in Scala as a private field and a getter.

Look at the decompiled bytecode of the `TestSec08` initialization:

```
/* Initializing private field `fred` */
     0: aload_0
     1: new           #95                 // class Person
     4: dup
     5: ldc           #102                // String Fred
     7: invokespecial #105                // Method Person."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    10: putfield      #78                 // Field fred:LPerson;
/* Initializing private field `wilma` */
    13: aload_0
    14: new           #95                 // class Person
    17: dup
    18: ldc           #107                // String Wilma
    20: invokespecial #105                // Method Person."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    23: putfield      #80                 // Field wilma:LPerson;
/* Initializing private field `barney` */
    26: aload_0
    27: new           #95                 // class Person
    30: dup
    31: ldc           #109                // String Barney
    33: invokespecial #105                // Method Person."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    36: putfield      #82                 // Field barney:LPerson;
    39: aload_0
/* Calling getter for field `fred` */
    40: invokevirtual #111                // Method fred:()LPerson;
/* Getting the array of fred's friends */
    43: invokevirtual #115                // Method Person.friends:()Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer;
    46: aload_0
/* Calling getter for field `wilma` */
    47: invokevirtual #117                // Method wilma:()LPerson;
/* Adding wilma to fred's friends */
    50: invokevirtual #123                // Method scala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer.$plus$eq:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer;
```

If you also look at the line number tables, you'll notice that the start of this method and the `fred` getter correspond to the same line in the source code: `val fred = new Person("Fred")`.

So when the debugger stops at the line `val fred = new Person("Fred")` for the first time, it is initializing the private field with `new Person("Fred")`, and when it goes to that line after that, it is executing the synthesized getter method.